# How to create system modal dialog in Java?

Tags: java, modal-dialog, system

I would like to create system modal dialog. I mean a dialog that blocks the entire system screen, not a particular application. So far I found Application modality and Toolkit modality that might be replaced even with manual disabling blocked frames, but still no function to lock the entire screen as in a native application. How can I do this?

Comment: Grammar and clarity improvements, and this can still use more explanation of what has been tried and why it will not work, and the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far I found the answer:
There is a note on docs.oracle.com:

> **Note :** The new modality model does not implement a system modality,
>   which blocks all applications (including Java applications) that are
>   displayed on the desktop while a modal dialog box is active.

As I can see, I just have to seek different way for my task.